# Entity Framework Core 7 Full Text Search Index Annotation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, full-text-search, ef-core-7.0

Is there a way to annotate a string field in a class with Entity Framework Core 7 to create a full text index on that column, and if yes how can I run a query with EF Core 7 to search that column?

I'm not asking for the fluent API but for a field annotation in my C# class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
[Index(nameof(Url))]
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

If you want Composite index:

```
[Index(nameof(FirstName), nameof(LastName))]
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations

Update:

If you already have "using System;" on your class, you have to put a full qualify or say wich 'Index' do you wanna use:

```
[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Index(nameof(Url))]
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Or

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Index = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IndexAttribute;

namespace Your.Namespace
{
[Index(nameof(Url))]
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but notice that I wrote "Full Text Search Index" which is a database specific full text search feature of SqlServer, MySql etc.

Comment: Oh, ok, ok... I'm sorry. Thank you!